# How to find a linearly independent vector?

Tags: vector-spaces

Given two vectors $(1,2,8),(0,1,9)$ find a 3rd vector that is linearly independent from these two vectors.

I sort of have an idea how to go about solving the problem but I'm not 100% sure. I'm know we just want to find a vector that can't be written as the sum of the two given vectors but how exactly do I go about finding one such vector?

**Got it now many thanks to all the helpers some brilliant explanations.**

Comment: Have you learned about cross product of two vectors?

Comment: Yes although I'm not sure how that would relate? Something to do with not being able to make that vector since it is perpendicular?

Comment: The result of a cross product is always perpendicular on the two given input vectors of the cross product. Because you have now 2 vectors which span a 2 dimensional plane and also a third perpendicular on those, you can create now all vectors in ${\mathbb{R}}^3$. So all vectors are linearly independent of each other then.

Comment: Hint: the set of all linear combinations of your two vectors, denoted $\operatorname{span}[(1,2,8),(0,1,9)]$, is a plane in $\Bbb R^3$.  If you choose *any* vector which is not in that plane, you'll have found a third vector which forms a linearly independent set with your two vectors.

Comment: @Pedro How exactly would this span be a plain in $\mathbb{R^3}$ it seems to me like it would be all vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ since you can make any vector in $\mathbb{R^3}$ by taking a linear combination of the two given vectors?

Comment: @Bye_World thanks, is it now correct?

Comment: Give or take an isomorphism...

Comment: @Pedro Except that your language sounds a little bit awkward -- yes.  You're correct.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here: if a set spans a space, you'll never find any vectors that can't be expressed as a linear combination of your set. So those two vectors *either* span $\mathbb{R}^3$, *or* are part of a larger linearly independent set, but not both.

Comment: @CallumK It's completely incorrect to believe you can make any vector in $\Bbb R^{3}$ from just two vectors.  For example, how can you add or subtract multiples of $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ to get $(0,0,1)$?  You can't -- there's no way.  If two vectors are linearly independent, then their span is a 2 dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^{3}$, i.e., a plane.  A good rule to know is: **# of linearly independent vectors = dimension of span**.

Comment: @CallumK If you have two vectors they can at most span a plain. Just imagine before your eyes two vectors somewhere in a 3D space (both originated at the origin). If those point in the same direction, you span a line. If those point not in the same direction, they span a plain. If you put a third vector on top of them which does not point in the direction of a plain, you span the full 3 dimensional space.

Comment: @Pedro That explanation was nice thanks. I'm still struggling to piece together a final answer.

Comment: @user46944 yes I see that but my vectors aren't $(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ so I was wrongly assuming because you have that all components of the first vector are non-zero then you can take a linear combination to find any vector you wish by just altering $c_1, c_2$ to get the vector you desire.

Answer (score 6):

I like your idea about finding a vector that can't be written as a sum of the two vectors above.  Let's take a look at what that would look like.

Every possible sum of these two vectors can be expressed as $c_{1}(1,2,8) + c_{2}(0,1,9)$ for some $c_{1}, c_{2}$ in $\Bbb R$.  So, all possible sums can be expressed in the form $(c_{1}, 2c_{1} + c_{2}, 8c_{1} + 9c_{2})$.

We want to come up with a third vector $(v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3})$ that can't be expressed in the above form.  Whatever $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ you pick for the linear combination above, we need that the third component $v_{3}$ is exactly $8c_{1} + 9c_{2}$.  Let's pick a vector whose third component is *different* from this (i.e., pick $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$, and fill in the first two components of $(c_{1}, 2c_{1} + c_{2}, 8c_{1} + 9c_{2})$, but make the third component different from this).

So, even though you can pick $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ to be anything, I will pick $c_{1} = c_{2} = 1$.  Then the vector I will construct will be:

$(1c_{1}, 2c_{1} + 1c_{2}, 11) = (1, 2 + 1, 11) = (1, 3, 11)$

Notice that I made the third component different from $8c_{1} + 9c_{2} = 8 + 9 = 17$.  Then this new vector can't be written as a linear combination of the previous two vectors, because that's how we constructed it.

Comment: Brilliant answer.

Comment: @CallumK It's all based on your initial suggestion.  Good for you for thinking in the right way.

Comment: Cheers @Karl! :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple method: you want to find a vector $(a,b,c)$ such that the system
$$
x(1,2,8)+y(0,1,9)=(a,b,c)
$$
has no solution. It's a linear system because it can be written as
$$
\begin{cases}
x=a\\
2x+y=b\\
8x+9y=c
\end{cases}
$$
The matrix of this system is
$$
\left[\!\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 0 & a \\
2 & 1 & b \\
8 & 9 & c
\end{array}\!\right]
$$
If we proceed with Gaussian elimination we get
\begin{align}
\left[\!\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 0 & a \\
2 & 1 & b \\
8 & 9 & c
\end{array}\!\right]
&\to
\left[\!\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 0 & a \\
0 & 1 & b-a \\
0 & 9 & c-8a
\end{array}\!\right]
\\&\to
\left[\!\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 0 & a \\
0 & 1 & b-a \\
0 & 0 & c-8a-9b+9a
\end{array}\!\right]
\end{align}
so we just need to have
$$
a-9b+c\ne0
$$
and we can choose whatever values of the parameters, so for example $a=1$, $b=0$ and $c=0$.

Of course infinitely many other choices are possible.

A different method is finding a non zero vector which is orthogonal to the two given vectors; if the vector is $(a,b,c)$ we get
$$
\begin{cases}
a+2b+8c=0\\
b+9c=0
\end{cases}
$$
This gives $a=-2b-8c$ and $b=-9c$. So we can set $c=1$ and get $b=-9$, $a=10$.

With the first method we find *all* vectors that solve our problem, but your task is just finding one, so take your pick.

Comment: Very nice also cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to add to an old question, but it came up for me and I think this method may be useful for others. The method is equivalent to @egreg's answer, but maybe a bit easier to implement programmatically when you need the last vector to make a complete basis - a square matrix of linearly independent rows and columns - as in this question.

A matrix with linearly independent rows has a non-zero determinant, so if you want to find the vector $(a,b,c)$ to make a complete basis, we need

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
1 & 2 & 8 \\
0 & 1 & 9 \\
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0
$$

The determinant can be computed with the elements in the top row and the minors (the Laplace expansion), so we get

$$
a 
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 8 \\
1 & 9 \\
\end{vmatrix}
- b
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 8 \\
0 & 9 \\
\end{vmatrix}
+ c
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
\neq 0
$$

which again is

$$
10a - 9b + c \neq 0
$$

Any $(a,b,c)$ that satisfies that will be linearly independent. A really simple approach would be just to pick one of the elements with non-zero coefficients and set it to $1$, and set the other elements to zero. In this case none of the coefficients are zero, so $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ are all linearly independent with the first two vectors you gave.

Comment: Yes, this is my strategy, too. After all, the two given vectors span a plane, while the whole space is three-dimensional. So almost any “random” triple $(r,s,t)$ should do the trick.

Comment: That's a really interesting way to look at it. Statistically, if you chose a random 3D vector, there's a 100% chance that it will be linearly independent. That being said, using the determinants is useful if you're working with integers and especially finite fields (eg binary matrices).

Comment: Absolutely. You take your “random” third vector and check by computing the determinant. Exactly what you did, which is why you got my only plus-one on this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the [orthogonal complement](https://ttps://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/Interactive_Linear_Algebra_(Margalit_and_Rabinoff)/06%3A_Orthogonality/6.02%3A_Orthogonal_Complements) for any *n* dimensional space. In MATLAB:

```
A = [1 2 8 ; 0 1 9];
p = null(sym(A))
10
-9
 1
dot(p,A(1,:))
0
dot(p,A(2,:))
0
```