# Vector spaces and linear dependence?

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm struggling with this question:

Find $\alpha$ such that the set of vectors is linearly dependent.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
7
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
11\\ 
-5
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
9\\ 
\alpha
\end{bmatrix}$$

I think the way to approach this problem is to try and find $\alpha$ such that the span of these 3 vectors has non trivial solutions but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing it. I believe Jordan-Gaussian elimination can be used but I'm not exactly sure how to get non-trivial solutions out.

Comment: The $\operatorname{span}$ of a set of vectors doesn't really have *solutions*.  What's the definition of linear (in)dependence?

Comment: Look carefully at those three vectors and the first two components. How would you write one of the three as a linear combination of the others?

Comment: The first two "rows" form simultaneous equations $x + 2y = 1$ and $2x + 11y = 9$, which you can solve. Then $\alpha$ is determined to be $7x - 5y$ (if you want linear dependence!).

Comment: If the linear combinations of the 3 vectors have at least one non trivial solution then it is dependent. (i.e. all constants are zero). And if the only solutions are when all constants are zero then it is linearly independent.

Comment: @James okay that seems easy enough to do but I don't understand exactly why thay would work could you elaborate further?

Comment: See also [a question that was posted 4 hours ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192890/how-to-find-a-linearly-independent-vector).

Comment: Name the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ respectively. They are linearly dependent iff you can find a solution to $xv_1 + yv_2 + z v_1 = 0$ where $x,y,z$ are not all $0$. So, assume there is such a solution for $\alpha$, then $xv_1 + yv_2 = -z v_3$. As we are in a vector space, and $-z$ is a non-zero scalar, (you actually need to prove this), then you can divide through by it. Now you have the equation $x' v_1 + y' v_2 = v_3$. The first two coordinates of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ now determine what $x',y'$ are, then you can plug in and read off $\alpha$. Is that clear?

Comment: ^That's the semi-theoretical way of thinking about it. More concretely, a set of vectors is linearly dependent if you can write one of the vectors in terms of a linear sum of the others, you can search for $x$ and $y$ so that $xv_1 + yv_2$ has the first two coordinates "right", but, then the 3rd coordinate is fixed, and, so, that must be $\alpha$, if the $v_i$s are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: solve: $$\text{det}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 11 & 9 \\ 7 & -5 & \alpha \end{pmatrix}=0$$.

As an explanation for this criteria, you note that L.I of these column vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ means that the equation $xv_1+yv_2+zv_3 = 0 \to [v_1,v_2,v_3]\cdot\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = 0 \to \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = 0 \to [v_1,v_2,v_3]$ is invertible $\to \text{det} [v_1,v_2,v_3] \neq 0$.

Comment: Where did this come from?