# How to find a 3rd vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is linearly independent to 2 other vectors. Revisiting.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was trying an exercise in which they give you 2 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and you need to find a $3^{rd}$ vector that is linearly independent, and although I found a solution, it didn't convince me at all. Searching for a solution for this kind of problem, I found [this other solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192890/how-to-find-a-linearly-independent-vector). The way they solve it is the one that I actually used, but there is one thing that I don't understand why really works.

If you make the combination of the vectors not apply for one of the values of the vector, I see that (obviously) that linear combination isn't applying in that case, but wouldn't it be possible that another combination of parameters that add the vectors be actually equal to 0?

The main thing is, why making the linear combination not be equal to zero for a set of parameters assures that it will happen the same with some other sets of parameters.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  This seems very vague and convoluted to me.  Can you give a concrete example of your problem?

Comment: @saulspatz an example of this appears in the link that appears in the text. Basically, how can we assure that the vector that we found isn't also a linear combination of the other 2 vectors but with other parameters different from the ones we used?

Comment: That other question has some good answers already.  You should also check out [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).  The span of a basis of $k$ linearly-independent vectors is a $k$ dimensional subspace, and the set of vectors orthogonal to the basis is a subspace, but the set of vectors linearly independent to the basis is not a subspace because they CAN include a component in the span but MUST include a component not in the span

Comment: Have you tried to find one?  How will you find $c_1$ and $c_2$ to make the first two elements come out to $1$ and $3$?

Comment: @saulspatz to mine I found a solution which I checked if it was correct by calculating the rank of the column vector matrix of the 2 given vectors and the one I found.

Comment: @hacatu I'm not sure if I understand it completely. Do you know where I could find a  formal demonstration of that?

Comment: Eg in 3d the span of 2 linearly independent vectors is a plane containing the origin (2d subspace), the set of vectors orthogonal to both vectors (and hence orthogonal to any vector in the plane) is a line (the normal to the plane).  However, the set of linearly independent vectors is all of 3d space EXCEPT the plane spanned by the two vectors.  The formal term is orthogonal complement.  The orthogonal complement is a vector space which is (aside from the origin) a subset of the set of linearly independent vectors